# Angular HttpClient Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status

Tags: angular, typescript, apache, http

I am attempting to use HttpClient to get a json return from a file that I have locked using htaccess and htpasswd on my web server. I can run the get/post request on postman with the Authorization header and it returns fine. When I run it in angular, I get the error in the title along with a 401 error.

Here is the function that triggers the HttpRequest

```js
  getConfig(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('myurlhere/myfile.json', { responseType: 'json' })
  }
```

Here is my interceptor - and yes, the console.log fires and logging the result shows the the request with the headers appended.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor() { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    req = req.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
      }
    })
    console.log('INTERCEPTED')
    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

There are a lot of similar issues here, but nothing seems to be working. The 401 return is labeled OPTIONS and I've pieced together what that means, just can't find a way around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FIX**
It ended up being an issue server-side with htaccess and CORS setup.

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Authorization"

<Files config.json>
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Authentication Required"
AuthUserFile C:\xampp\htdocs\.htpasswd
Options -Indexes
<LimitExcept OPTIONS>
  Require valid-user
</LimitExcept>
</Files>
```

I needed to add the `LimitExcept` block, then it started working!

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is an issue with the `request`, the `request` object (`req`) is immutable, so you have to define a new property and clone the request to it, then update it

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor() { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const modifiedReq = req.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
      }
    })
    console.log('INTERCEPTED')
    return next.handle(modifiedReq); // pass the modified request to the handle method
  }
}
```

check the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#setting-default-headers) for more info

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it's the same result. From what I've read, Authorization headers aren't supported in the initial request in HttpClient, so the server responds with an OPTIONS response...I've been driving myself crazy trying to figure this out.